# Django Model reverse relationship having a string with the name of it

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to implement a Django Rest Framework view that returns the dependencies tree of a model instance object. This is the code for such view:

```
class RoomTypeDependencies(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request, pk):
        room_type = models.RoomType.objects.get(pk=pk)

        dependency_tree = self.get_object_dependencies(room_type)

        return Response(dependency_tree)

    def get_object_dependencies(self, instance):
        fields = instance.__class__._meta.get_fields()
        dependencies_to_return = []
        for field in fields:
            print(field.name)
            if field.__class__.__name__ == 'ManyToOneRel':
                dependency_to_return = []
                dependent_instances = getattr(instance, field.name)
                for dependent_instance in dependent_instances:
                    dependency_to_return.append(self.get_object_dependencies(dependent_instance))
                dependencies_to_return.append({field.__class__.__name__: dependency_to_return})

        return Response({str(instance): dependencies_to_return})
```

Everything seems to work, but I expected `getattr(instance, field.name)` to return the dependent instances corresponding to the reverse relationship, just like using `model_object_instance.reverse_relationshio_name` pattern, but it returns a **RelatedManager** object instead. The problem in my case is that I have the reverse relationship name in a string variable (`field.name`).

Comment: You should post your models.  You shouldn't have to do those gymnastics the `fields` of your model.  Since you are using DRF you should handle customization to what gets returned with a `Serializer` class.

Comment: @Red Cricket I would post all my models in that case. I want to implement an algorithm to return the dependency tree of an object instance of any model.

Comment: Hey! Somebody gave me the right answer, but when I finished testing it, he had erased it!!!

Comment: If the answer works you should post it as the answer or update your original question with it. :)